# Position fixed и горизонтальный скролл

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть header, 2 блока справа и слева и по центру блок с контентом. Задача закрепить все блоки так, чтобы при прокрутки двигался только центральный блок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Если использовать position fixed, все конечно работает, но как только появляется горизонтальный скролл -начинаются проблемы. Верхняя шапка режется, при прокрутке в право левый блок наезжает на контент.

В качестве решения можно с помощью js вычислять margin-left при событии scroll, однако проблема возникает на телефонах, когда событие срабатывает только тогда, когда закончится анимация движения, в результате чего блоки ездят (тоже происходит и в сафари под маком).

Есть ли какие-то варианты решения такой проблемы ?

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос пример кода, демонстрирующий данную проблему.

Comment: К сожалению сейчас не успею это сделать. Но в ближайшее время попробую оформить несколько своих вариантов и показать Вам через http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

Я бы рекомендовал Вам сделать адаптивный дизайн... При котором вверх остается закрепленным, а боковые панели уходят в стороны, сделать можно, например, этой библиотекой: http://www.berriart.com/sidr/
Сам пользуюсь недолго, но пока особых нареканий не было. 
Соответственно для телефона уходят две панели, для планшета можно одну оставить. Также одна панель остается в том случае, как только появляется горизонтальный скролл.
Можно сделать чтобы панели открывались по жесту.
Кстати, вместе с ней использую: http://simianstudios.com/portamento/ быть может Вам пригодиться.
Второй вариант, это на мобильных устройствах задать `<meta name="viewport" content="width=500">` Где 500, это ширина, при который не будет горизонтального скрола. Точно не помню, но по-моему в этом случае, при увеличении, все блоки останутся на месте и ничего ехать не будет.